# What is PowerPoint's equivalent of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I've run into an unusual issue which involves fonts and various alternative systems - hear me out...

So I've been working on a PowerPoint presentation with a bunch of custom icon fonts and whatnot. Now I've got to switch back to my Linux system where PowerPoint doesn't run. So I tried the web version, which works but it doesn't recognise my system's fonts for some reason. LibreOffice Impress does, but the animations are janky and just generally not as clean as PowerPoint, which is dissapointing but predictable.

So my question was, in Word for instance, I can export the docoument as a PDF and it will with most certainty look exactly the same as the original document on just about any device or any viewer. My question is, is there a similar format for PowerPoints that preserves animations, and looks as clean as the original presentation, but can be opened outside of PowerPoint, such as a browser?

Thanks

Comment: You could save the presentation as video.

Comment: I'd considered that, but then all my timings are fixed, which is not ideal. I was hoping that I could export to HTML but I don't seem to have much luck with that

Comment: Best to present it on a Windows system. Borrow one for the presentation.

Comment: Powerpoint has a large number of historical and alternative formats you could save as that might be better understood by alternative viewers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoJQs.png

Comment: @John Thanks I'm thinking about just biting the bullet and doing that. Annoying but the only approach which is all-encompasing...

Comment: @Mokubai I did look into this list, but most of them exhibit the same problem. Those that don't impose other restrictions. The SVG was the closest to what I'm after, but also doesn't export animations, and each slide is a separate file.

Comment: By default, presentation saved as videos have one slide change each 5 seconds (you can change it). This is a rather stupid answer, but you can use the play/pause button of your video player to pass the slides (or its keyboard shortcut, typically the space bar). This is only useful if you can switch off any on screen message or symbol from the player.

Comment: @krollspell hahaha 10 points for creativity, I love that approach

Comment: >> So I tried the web version, which works but it doesn't recognise my system's fonts for some reason. ... Yes, because then you're running the presentation on a web server, not on your own system.  But have you tried embedding the fonts in your presentation? I'm not sure whether this will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: They should already be embedded. Regardless, browsers can detect the list of installed fonts. As far as I can tell, the presentation is rendered into HTML on the server, but the browser still does the rasterisation, hence the fonts should be picked up from the system

Comment: @J-Cake My tests suggest otherwise. I created a file with several lines of text, each set to a different font. Then I copied the text box containing all the text, pasted back as PNG and sent that to back, aligned it with the original. This makes any font substitution very obvious when the file's opened elsewhere. Saved the file with no fonts embedded, just needed glyphs embedded, all embedded.  Results:
https://1drv.ms/p/s!Am2R87k-gmnplwJPYrn2Sp7G5VeB?e=eAujrW
https://1drv.ms/p/s!Am2R87k-gmnplwEGFAHdDnpLpbyZ?e=OcjZbR
https://1drv.ms/p/s!Am2R87k-gmnplwBswfGlB6S3LpW0?e=lrzpMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF has a little-known and not widely used presentation transition system. I don't know whether Powerpoint, when exporting to PDF, can generate these transitions, because I've never tried. Give it a go.

If not, you could export your PowerPoint as a PDF, and then re-add the transitions using `cpdf`:

https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanualch7.html#x11-690007

You might also set up some other things such as the Initial Page View. Here's a page from Adobe on the topic, including how to manually add transitions to a PDF:

https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/setting-pdfs-presentation.html

Transitions only play in Adobe Reader when you're in full screen mode.

Comment: Oh wow that's amazing. I didn't know that existed in PDF. It does seem like either PowerPoint doesn't export animations, or Chrome's built-in PDF renderer doesn't support it, which is a shame, but cool anyway

Comment: Correct. PPT doesn't export media, animations, transitions, ActiveX/OLE objects etc to PDF using its own File | Save As feature and as far as I know, no other PDF add-ins (Acrobat etc) do either.  Partially because some of this stuff just isn't supported in PDF, partially because ... well, they just don't.